# build 2D array with non zero values from a 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d symmetrical numpy array:

```
A = [[    0.     0.     0. ...     0.     0.     0.]
     [    0.     0.     0. ...     0.     0.     0.]
     [    0.     0.     0. ...     0.     0.     0.]
     ...
     [    0.     0.     0. ... 15351.  4299.  1738.]
     [    0.     0.     0. ...     0. 12393.  4374.]
     [    0.     0.     0. ...     0.     0. 15632.]]
```

It is a symmetrical matrix where A[i,j] = A[j,i]
I want to create another 2D array where values should not be zero but nonzero values of A. I have tried np.where and np.nonzero options but I am failing to create a same dimensional array in python. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What shape will your output array be? What if the number of nonzero elements is not easily factorizable?

Comment: I have used np.nonzero to find the length of row and col. or I can do like row,col = np.where(A>1e-10) and I found row = 2080 and col = 2080.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. You need to explain your strategy to convert from a flat list of nonzeros to a two-dimensional matrix.